# dpkg: error: failed to open package info file '/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status' for reading

Tags: macos, terminal, dpkg

I followed [this link](http://macappstore.org/dpkg/) to install dpkg tool on my Macbook.

After that, I try to execte command

```
 sudo dpkg -i sometool.deb
```

I get error :

```
dpkg: error: failed to open package info file '/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Why? How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Check there is '/usr/local/var' directory kept or not

Comment: `usr/local/var` is there.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Stratodesk "NoTouch OS"

Answer (score 0):

check there is two file named 'status' and 'status-old' in /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg .
Then move the status file to your backup directory or delete the 'status' file .
Then copy 'status-old' as /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status .

**Terminal Command:**

```
sudo mv /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status /path/to/your/backup/directory
sudo cp /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status-old /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status
```

If you didn't find the file .There is a backup for you dpkg in **/var/backups/dpkg.status.0** or **/usr/local/var/backups/dpkg.status.0** .
So use the following command to recreate it.

```
cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
```

(or)

```
cp /usr/local/var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: There is neither `/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg` nor `/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg`, but there is `/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg` directory with content `alternatives info  lock  lock-frontend parts  updates`.

Comment: check it is located in "/var/lib/dpkg" . If you find there add a symlink to "/usr/local/var/lib/"

Comment: I don't have `/var/lib/dpkg`. So...what now ? :D

Comment: Got `cp: /var/backups/dpkg.status.0: No such file or directory`

Comment: neither `/var/backups` nor `/usr/local/var/backups/` have `dpkg.status.0` on my Macbook.